# Creating external Javascript Libraries

Tags: javascript

How can I create external Javascript libraries which i can use in my web application project created in Visual studio?

Comment: You mean like JQuery, MooTools?

Comment: Store your JavaScript code in a file and include it where you want to have it? I don't really understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can create library simply as a file, saved with the extension .js, that contains some JavaScript code.

Add a < script > tag, defined on the page(s) that uses the library, used to "connect" to the library

If library name is displaydate.js

You can include it in your code with this tag
< script src="displaydate.js" >

Refer: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external2.shtml